# FATAL Error: [config validation of [monitoring].enabled]: definition for this key is missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I upgraded the ELK stack to version 8.0.0 and this is the error I am getting in the logs of my Kibana pod: "FATAL  Error: [config validation of [monitoring].enabled]: definition for this key is missing". How should I fix this? [kibana.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKQqi.png)

Comment: Please, update your question and share your `kibana.yml` configuration file.

Comment: I've updated it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

From 8.x.x, the general monitoring settings (monitoring.enabled) is no longer supported. Take a look at the settings that are at different levels in [Kibana's monitoring settings page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/monitoring-settings-kb.html). For you, removing the settings will run the kibana.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue with elk 8.x.x "config validation of xpack.fleet.enabled: definition for this key is missing". after I removed xpack.fleet.enabled from kibana.yml issue was fixed. Take a look at this [fleet settings in kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/fleet-settings-kb.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for contributing! It's not clear what you did: did you remove `xpack.fleet.enabled` from `kibana.yaml`? If so, please add the verb *remove* because now there is a verb missing in your sentence :)

Comment: I have removed xpack fleet from kibana.ymal